# CSS convert table columns into full-width stacked elements

Tags: html, css, html-table

I've found many ways to create a 'tableless' table layout using only DIVs, but very little about the opposite.

I have more than a few html pages with a table structure, and they all refer to a common CSS file. The tables have a simple 2-column layout as follows:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>category</th>
      <td>description</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>category</th>
      <td>description</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to be able to transform the layout of the table through **CSS only**, in order to make it look like a 'single-column table' if you will, with both categories and descriptions stacked on top of another within the full-width of the table. I've tried display:block and width:100% but it doesn't work **cross-browser**.

Thoughts?

Comment: For Internet Explorer (at least <= 9) I’d say: Forget it! That browser can not be convinced to display table rows/cells as anything else than that.

Comment: I really hope you're wrong :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve the result you want if you `float` each cell. 
See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/t3ZaM/

Works in FF, Chrome, Opera, Safari, IE9 and 10 but I can't check for older versions of IE because I don't have them.

Comment: I just tried this in IE 7/8 and it's not working. I'm beginning to think what CBroe said is true :(

Comment: I'm sure there must be a workaround. If only I could test in older IE versions....